# How bad is this corrosion and what would cause it?

Tags: corrosion, copper-pipe

Not sure if this is a useful picture but I have some copper pipe that is green with corrosion / oxidation and wondering if this is something I should replace. And what the cause would be? Is it galvanic or something else?

Here’s another photo with example of nearby solder joints.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Condensation, if you're lucky.

Comment: What is its function? There's obviously a lot of PEX here, and this pipe appears to be considerably older.  It probably is just condensation and old-age. No sign of a joint nearby with corrosive flux not removed or that sort of thing.

Comment: Then again, if you have the wrong sort of water chemistry, this might be the only pipe that hasn't **yet** been replaced due to the water eating pinholes from the inside...does it drip?

Comment: Many things can cause corrosion Sheetrock/drywall shortly after hurricane Katrina imported from china was known to cause this but I would lean to moisture because it is much worse on 1 end compared to the other.

Comment: @Ecnerwal function is to carry cold water from near the house’s water main entrance to a few faucets — mostly kitchen. The house is probably around 60-80% PEX at this point at least and I’m trying to decide if I should remove it as well.

Answer (score 2):

For the solder joints, get a nice hot (but not scalding) bucket of water (perhaps with a spoonful of baking soda in it) and a rag and wipe them down if they are particularly green - **that** is generally failure to remove/clean flux after soldering.

Nothing there looks particularly dire - the above is basically preventative maintenance to reduce any further corrosion from leftover flux before it becomes an issue. It's *finally* doing what the person who soldered these should have done, probably decades ago (nice char on the framing, too!)

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this.

Answer (score 1):

Not galvanic, most likely cosmetic/surface. Apparently it is occasionally wet with condensation. If it is wetted from a leak somewhere else, you have a different problem. I would clean it with sandpaper and watch it to determine how it is getting wet.